# What does Single Turn, Double Turn and Triple Turn mean in brewing?

Tags: brewing, breweries, craft-beers

I was going through a brochure in brewing and it mentioned Single Turn, Double Turn and Triple turn brewing. However, it did not mention what those mean. I would really appreciate if anyone with knowledge of this enlighten me on this.

Comment: Can you add a link to the brochure or brewery in question as it may be helpful.

Comment: This is what they have: Total Price = Brewhouse Turn + Ingredients + Optional Services + Packaging
BREWHOUSE TURN: Base fee which includes up to 30bbls packaged yield per turn (yield
dependent on batch process) and up to 18 days in fermentation vessel.
• SINGLE TURN – $5,000
• DOUBLE TURN – $7,800
• TRIPLE TURN – $11,500

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand a "turn" is a term from Contract Brewing.  Though it seems like it's slightly ambiguous term with different meanings depending on context.  In this case it refers to a "turn" using the brewery and includes time in a fermentation vessel.  Which is to say for $5000 you can use the facilities to brew 30 barrels of beer from start to finish, plus extra charges for ingredients and packaging (canning/bottling/kegging).

Internally brewers will also use "turn" as shorthand for "turnaround time" which only refers to how quickly a batch of beer can go from the grain mill to the fermentation vessel and is used for planning how many different batches of beer can be produced in a day.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is turn = [shift](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shift) (meaning that they can pack up to 90bbls per day if the packaging department works 24 hours per day).